# material design not render dynamic elements out of screen in chrome 69.0.3497.100

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, material-design

STACK:
angular: 1.4.9
angular-material: 1.1.10

DESCRIPTION:
I dynamically add elements on page using $compile, in google chrome(69.0.3497.100) if input element out of screen it not rendered.
Render only labels.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DuUE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Find decision:

```css
md-input-container {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```